# 'Uncategorized' Xcode Error

Tags: xcode4.3

I'm having this WEIRD Xcode error - Uncategorized error.
It seems to look for a file which doesn't exist. 
The problem is that I don't see any reference to that file on my project.

Is there any place else that Xcode saves its project file references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources